# How to submit the react-hook-form by using Editable in Chakra UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I use `Controller` in `Editable` component from Chakra UI.
As you can see below code, I can submit the form via `<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>` and `onFormSubmit()` function works.

**Editable with submit typed Button (works)**

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Editable, EditableInput, EditablePreview, Flex, IconButton, Input, useEditableControls } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form"


export const RenameWithController = () => {
    const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm()

    const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log("data", data)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
                <Controller
                    name="name"
                    defaultValue="defaultValue"
                    control={control}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <Editable
                            isPreviewFocusable={false}
                            submitOnBlur={false}
                            value={field.value}
                        >
                            {(props) => (
                                <>
                                    <EditablePreview />
                                    <EditableInput {...field} />
                                    <EditableControls {...props} />
                                </>
                            )}
                        </Editable>
                    )}
                />
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

const EditableControls = ({ isEditing, onSubmit, onCancel, onEdit }) => {
    return isEditing ? (
        <ButtonGroup justifyContent="center" size="sm">
            <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Save</Button>
            <Button onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
    ) : (
        <Button onClick={onEdit}>Edit</Button>
    )
}
```

However, I want to remove `Submit` button and run `onFormSubmit()` function when I click on the `Save` button from `Editable`. However, it doesn't work. `onFormSubmit()` doesn't get called. See the below code my changes. I also provided a codesandbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/controller-editable-7cxqs4?file=/src/components/Edit.tsx:164-1312

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance on how to achieve this functionality.

**My Try (doesn't work)**

```
export const Edit = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

  const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("data", data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <Controller
          name="name"
          defaultValue="defaultValue"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Editable
              isPreviewFocusable={false}
              submitOnBlur={false}
              value={field.value}
              onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}
            >
              {(props) => (
                <>
                  <EditablePreview />
                  <EditableInput {...field} />
                  <EditableControls {...props} />
                </>
              )}
            </Editable>
          )}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

const EditableControls = ({ isEditing, onSubmit, onCancel, onEdit }) => {
  return isEditing ? (
    <ButtonGroup justifyContent="center" size="sm">
      <Button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      <Button onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  ) : (
    <Button onClick={onEdit}>Edit</Button>
  );
};
```